# converting Unicode letters with accents in ASCII/UTF8

Tags: c++, string, boost, unicode

I'm searching for a technique to convert a (JSON) string sent by a server containing something like this :

`...."Test \u00e9\u00e9\u00e9".....`

into something like :

`"Test ééé"`

I found a solution with `boost::replace_all(listFolder, "\\u00e9", "é");` and I'm using this boost function with the other letters `àùèê` etc.... but that's painful!

I wonder, is there a function to do this kind of conversion automatically?

The server will correctly treat strings that I send to it containing letters with accents if I use this function:

```
std::string fromLocale(std::string localeStr)
{
    boost::locale::generator g;
    g.locale_cache_enabled(true);
    std::locale loc = g(boost::locale::util::get_system_locale());
    return boost::locale::conv::to_utf<char>(localeStr,loc);
}
```

Unfortunately, the inverse of that code doesn't work to treat the strings sent by the server:

```
std::string toLocale(std::string utf8Str)
{
    boost::locale::generator g;
    g.locale_cache_enabled(true);
    std::locale loc = g(boost::locale::util::get_system_locale());
    return boost::locale::conv::from_utf<char>(utf8Str,loc);
}
```

Comment: It's not very clear to me what you're asking. Have a look at these snippets for decoding of JSON (Unicode) escapes: [`append_utf8` in this sample](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27799086/getting-values-from-a-json-file-using-boost-property-tree-with-multiple-element/27799928#27799928)

Comment: Readers note, as @sehe explained, that the string described as `"Test \u00e9\u00e9\u00e9"` is the string `"Test \\u00e9\\u00e9\\u00e9"`, i.e. \, u, 0, 0, e and 9 are individual characters.

Comment: yes Cheers and hth. - Alf

Answer (score 2):

The [JSON specification](http://www.json.org) allows for `"\uXXXX"` sequences for Unicode characters (amonst other `\X` escape sequences). If you are not using an existing JSON parser that handles decoding such sequences, you will have to decode them manually, eg:

```
// JSON uses Unicode, but is commonly encoded as UTF-8. However, Unicode
// characters that are encoded in "\uXXXX" format are expressed as UTF-16
// codeunit values, using surrogate pairs for codepoint values U+10000 and
// higher. This example uses C++11's std::u16string to handle UTF-16 parsing.
// If you are not using C++11 or later, you can replace it with std::wstring
// on platforms where wchar_t is 16bit, for instance.  If you want to handle
// the JSON using std::string/UTF-8 instead, you will have to tweak this
// parsing accordingly...

std::u16string str = ...; // JSON quoted-string value, eg: "Test \u00e9\u00e9\u00e9"...
std::u16string::size_type idx = 0;
while ((idx = str.find(u'\\', idx)) != std::u16string::npos)
{
    std::u16string replaceStr;
    std::u16string::size_type len = 2;

    char16_t ch = str.at(idx+1);
    switch (ch)
    {
        case u'\"':
        case u'\\':
        case u'/':
            replaceStr = ch;
            break;

        case u'b':
            replaceStr = u'\b';
            break;

        case u'f':
            replaceStr = u'\f';
            break;

        case u'n':
            replaceStr = u'\n';
            break;

        case u'r':
            replaceStr = u'\r';
            break;

        case u't':
            replaceStr = u'\t';
            break;

        case u'u':
        {
            std::u16string hexStr = str.substr(idx+2, 4);
            len += hexStr.size();

            std::basic_istringstream<char16_t> iss(hexStr);
            std::uint_least16_t value;
            if (!(iss >> std::hex >> value))
            {
                // illegal value, do something
            }

            replaceStr = static_cast<char16_t>(value);
            break;
        }

        default:
            // illegal sequence, do something
            break;
    }

    str.replace(idx, len, replaceStr);
    idx += replaceStr.size();
}
```

Comment: `unsigned short value` ought to be `std::uint_least16_t value` for the conversion to a `char16_t` (not `char`, of course).

Comment: @TobySpeight Why? `unsigned short` is guaranteed to be at least 16  bits. In fact, the only case where `std::uint_least16_t` will be anything other than a typedef to `unsigned short` is if `unsigned char` has 16 or more bits.

Comment: Yes, `unsigned short` may be wider than `std::uint_least16_t`.