# JSON Data using Boost

Tags: c++, json, boost

Is it possible to read the following data below using boost?

```
{
  "ok": true,
  "result": [
    {
      "update_id": 1235285,
      "message": {
        "message_id": 2,
        "from": {
          "id": 3325446,
          "is_bot": false,
          "first_name": "Test",
          "language_code": "en-PH"
        },
        "chat": {
          "id": 12532541,
          "first_name": "Test Account",
          "type": "private"
        },
        "date": 152014521,
        "text": "Test Message"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Look at boost::property_tree

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading json file with boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15206705/reading-json-file-with-boost)

Comment: Don't, boost::property_tree is very ugly and buggy.

Comment: @AndreKampling data is stored on std::string. It is not stored on file

Comment: @batch1999: Read the solution in the thread. It uses `std::stringstream`, so he can read a file or a string...

Comment: @AndreKampling i already done that but no success

Comment: @batch1999: It would be helpful to ask more specific. What are the problems, errors, ...?

Comment: i realy dont where the errors are because i am trying to show the data using MessageBox but the error shows on different class not on the code. I have tried the code on the link that you give.

Comment: @Arpegius That's bullshit. Boost Property is not ugly and certainly not buggy. What you mean is that it's not a general purpose JSON library. It's a property tree library. \[Apparently wishful thinking causes people to assume it's a JSON and an XML library. None of which is true, obviously]. If you don't need that, use a JSON library, really. But If property tree does fit the bill, it's fine. [Limitations are worded in all of the 12 lines of documentation for the JSON backend](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/property_tree/parsers.html#property_tree.parsers.json_parser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could see the [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15206705/1870232) in comment,

To summarize you can have like following to read from a file say `mfile.json` :

```
    boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
    boost::property_tree::read_json("myfile.json", pt);

    print_contents( pt );
```

where `print_contents` is:

```
void print_contents( const boost::property_tree::ptree& pt)
{
    using boost::property_tree::ptree;

    for (const auto& x: pt )
    {
        std::cout << x.first << ": " << x.second.get_value<std::string>() << std::endl;
        print_contents(x.second);
    }
}
```

[`See Here`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93229ace7c1d69ea)

---

<sup>*I could have closed it as duplicate, but looks like there was no "better" post for reading a json file*</sup>

Comment: there was an error on `for(const auto& x:pt)` where x is the error

Comment: @batch1999 see the linked demo. `x` is variable used in the range based for loop. Make sure you enable C++11 flag

Comment: `void TestBotDlg::OnConnectWebserver()
{
 tgapi bot(BOT_ID);
 string tmp = bot.getUpdates();
 
 stringstream ss;
 ss<<tmp;
 try
 {
  boost::property_tree ::ptree pt;
  boost::property_tree ::read_json (ss, pt);
  Print(pt);
 }
 catch(exception const& e)
 {
  MessageBox(e.what ());
 }
 
}

void TestBotDlg::Print(const boost::property_tree::ptree& pt )
{
 CString temp;
 boost::property_tree::ptree ;
 for(const auto& x: pt)
 {
  temp.Format("%s",x.second.get_value<std::string>());
  MessageBox(temp);
 }
}`

Comment: @batch1999 you're being a [help vampire](http://www.skidmore.edu/~pdwyer/e/eoc/help_vampire.htm). Ask a proper question. (The answer to your question now is obviously "Yes"). Edit your question to include a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and the expected outcome.

Comment: @sehe: This made my day! A lot of people are help vampires and you can meet a lot of them here on SO. Now I know this awesome term that hits the nail. Thank you!

Comment: but how can i implement on mfc application?

Comment: @batch1999 I gave you a code. Which you can **put/use** anywhere in C++ project, provided you have right library and right compiler.