# boost::property_tree::read_json in gcc 4.7.2 and boost 1.49 - compile-time errors

Tags: c++, boost

I have the following code:

```
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>

#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string input("{\"foo\":\"bar\"}");

  boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
  std::stringstream stream;
  stream << input;

  boost::property_tree::read_json(stream, pt);
}
```

In MSVC-11.0 with boost 1.54 this code compiles fine, but in gcc 4.7.2 with boost 1.49 this code gives me the following errors:

> In file included from
>   /usr/include/boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp:14:0,
>                    from main.cpp:1: /usr/include/boost/property_tree/detail/json_parser_read.hpp: In
>   instantiation of ‘void
>   boost::property_tree::json_parser::context::a_literal_val::operator()(boost::property_tree::json_parser::context::It,
>   boost::property_tree::json_parser::context::It) const [with
>   Ptree = boost::property_tree::basic_ptree,
>   std::basic_string >;
>   boost::property_tree::json_parser::context::It =
>   __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >]’:
>   /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/classic/core/scanner/scanner.hpp:148:13:
>   required from ‘static void
>   boost::spirit::classic::attributed_action_policy::call(const
>   ActorT&, boost::spirit::classic::nil_t, const IteratorT&, const
>   IteratorT&) [with ActorT =
>   boost::property_tree::json_parser::context,
>   std::basic_string > >::a_literal_val; IteratorT =
>   __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >]’
>   /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/classic/core/scanner/scanner.hpp:163:13:
>   required from ‘void
>   boost::spirit::classic::action_policy::do_action(const ActorT&,
>   AttrT&, const IteratorT&, const IteratorT&) const [with ActorT =
>   boost::property_tree::json_parser::context,
>   std::basic_string > >::a_literal_val; AttrT =
>   boost::spirit::classic::nil_t; IteratorT =
>   __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >]’
>   /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/classic/core/composite/actions.hpp:116:17:
>   required from ‘typename
>   boost::spirit::classic::parser_result, ScannerT>::type boost::spirit::classic::action::parse(const ScannerT&) const [with ScannerT =
>   boost::spirit::classic::scanner<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >,
>   boost::spirit::classic::scanner_policies,
>   boost::spirit::classic::kleene_star,
>   boost::spirit::classic::alternative,
>   boost::spirit::classic::unary_parser_category,
>   boost::spirit::classic::non_nested, boost::spirit::classic::is_lexeme>
>
> > , boost::spirit::classic::confix_parser,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::kleene_star,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::strlit,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::unary_parser_category,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::non_nested, boost::spirit::classic::is_lexeme>
> >     , boost::spirit::classic::iteration_policy>, boost::spirit::classic::match_policy,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::action_policy> >; ParserT =
> >     boost::spirit::classic::alternative > >,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::scanner_policies,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::kleene_star,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::alternative,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::unary_parser_category,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::non_nested, boost::spirit::classic::is_lexeme>
> >     , boost::spirit::classic::confix_parser,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::kleene_star,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::strlit,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::unary_parser_category,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::non_nested, boost::spirit::classic::is_lexeme>
> >     , boost::spirit::classic::iteration_policy>, boost::spirit::classic::match_policy,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::action_policy> >,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::nil_t, boost::spirit::classic::nil_t>,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::strlit >,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::strlit >,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::strlit >; ActionT =
> >     boost::property_tree::json_parser::context,
> >     std::basic_string > >::a_literal_val; typename
> >     boost::spirit::classic::parser_result, ScannerT>::type =
> >     boost::spirit::classic::match]’
> >     /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/classic/core/composite/alternative.hpp:67:59:
> >     recursively required from ‘typename
> >     boost::spirit::classic::parser_result, ScannerT>::type boost::spirit::classic::alternative::parse(const ScannerT&) const [with ScannerT =
> >     boost::spirit::classic::scanner<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::scanner_policies,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::kleene_star,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::alternative,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::unary_parser_category,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::non_nested, boost::spirit::classic::is_lexeme>
> >     , boost::spirit::classic::confix_parser,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::kleene_star,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::strlit,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::unary_parser_category,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::non_nested, boost::spirit::classic::is_lexeme>
> >     , boost::spirit::classic::iteration_policy>, boost::spirit::classic::match_policy,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::action_policy> >; A =
> >     boost::spirit::classic::alternative > >,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::scanner_policies,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::kleene_star,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::alternative,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::unary_parser_category,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::non_nested, boost::spirit::classic::is_lexeme>
> >     , boost::spirit::classic::confix_parser,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::kleene_star,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::strlit,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::unary_parser_category,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::non_nested, boost::spirit::classic::is_lexeme>
> >     , boost::spirit::classic::iteration_policy>, boost::spirit::classic::match_policy,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::action_policy> >,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::nil_t, boost::spirit::classic::nil_t>,
> >     boost::property_tree::json_parser::context,
> >     std::basic_string > >::a_string_val>,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::action > >,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::scanner_policies,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::kleene_star,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::alternative,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::unary_parser_category,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::non_nested, boost::spirit::classic::is_lexeme>
> >     , boost::spirit::classic::confix_parser,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::kleene_star,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::strlit,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::unary_parser_category,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::non_nested, boost::spirit::classic::is_lexeme>
> >     , boost::spirit::classic::iteration_policy>, boost::spirit::classic::match_policy,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::action_policy> >,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::nil_t, boost::spirit::classic::nil_t>,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::strlit >,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::strlit >,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::strlit >,
> >     boost::property_tree::json_parser::context,
> >     std::basic_string > >::a_literal_val> >; B =
> >     boost::spirit::classic::rule > >,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::scanner_policies,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::kleene_star,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::alternative,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::unary_parser_category,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::non_nested, boost::spirit::classic::is_lexeme>
> >     , boost::spirit::classic::confix_parser,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::kleene_star,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::strlit,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::unary_parser_category,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::non_nested, boost::spirit::classic::is_lexeme>
> >     , boost::spirit::classic::iteration_policy>, boost::spirit::classic::match_policy,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::action_policy> >,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::nil_t, boost::spirit::classic::nil_t>;
> >     typename
> >     boost::spirit::classic::parser_result, ScannerT>::type =
> >     boost::spirit::classic::match]’
> >     /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/classic/core/composite/alternative.hpp:67:59:
> >     required from ‘typename
> >     boost::spirit::classic::parser_result, ScannerT>::type boost::spirit::classic::alternative::parse(const ScannerT&) const [with ScannerT =
> >     boost::spirit::classic::scanner<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::scanner_policies,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::kleene_star,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::alternative,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::unary_parser_category,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::non_nested, boost::spirit::classic::is_lexeme>
> >     , boost::spirit::classic::confix_parser,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::kleene_star,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::strlit,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::unary_parser_category,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::non_nested, boost::spirit::classic::is_lexeme>
> >     , boost::spirit::classic::iteration_policy>, boost::spirit::classic::match_policy,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::action_policy> >; A =
> >     boost::spirit::classic::alternative > >,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::scanner_policies,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::kleene_star,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::alternative,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::unary_parser_category,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::non_nested, boost::spirit::classic::is_lexeme>
> >     , boost::spirit::classic::confix_parser,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::kleene_star,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::strlit,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::unary_parser_category,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::non_nested, boost::spirit::classic::is_lexeme>
> >     , boost::spirit::classic::iteration_policy>, boost::spirit::classic::match_policy,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::action_policy> >,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::nil_t, boost::spirit::classic::nil_t>,
> >     boost::property_tree::json_parser::context,
> >     std::basic_string > >::a_string_val>,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::action > >,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::scanner_policies,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::kleene_star,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::alternative,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::unary_parser_category,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::non_nested, boost::spirit::classic::is_lexeme>
> >     , boost::spirit::classic::confix_parser,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::kleene_star,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::strlit,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::unary_parser_category,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::non_nested, boost::spirit::classic::is_lexeme>
> >     , boost::spirit::classic::iteration_policy>, boost::spirit::classic::match_policy,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::action_policy> >,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::nil_t, boost::spirit::classic::nil_t>,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::strlit >,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::strlit >,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::strlit >,
> >     boost::property_tree::json_parser::context,
> >     std::basic_string > >::a_literal_val> >,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::rule > >,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::scanner_policies,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::kleene_star,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::alternative,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::unary_parser_category,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::non_nested, boost::spirit::classic::is_lexeme>
> >     , boost::spirit::classic::confix_parser,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::kleene_star,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::strlit,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::unary_parser_category,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::non_nested, boost::spirit::classic::is_lexeme>
> >     , boost::spirit::classic::iteration_policy>, boost::spirit::classic::match_policy,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::action_policy> >,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::nil_t, boost::spirit::classic::nil_t> >; B =
> >     boost::spirit::classic::rule > >,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::scanner_policies,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::kleene_star,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::alternative,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::unary_parser_category,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::non_nested, boost::spirit::classic::is_lexeme>
> >     , boost::spirit::classic::confix_parser,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::kleene_star,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::strlit,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::unary_parser_category,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::non_nested, boost::spirit::classic::is_lexeme>
> >     , boost::spirit::classic::iteration_policy>, boost::spirit::classic::match_policy,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::action_policy> >,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::nil_t, boost::spirit::classic::nil_t>;
> >     typename
> >     boost::spirit::classic::parser_result, ScannerT>::type =
> >     boost::spirit::classic::match]’
> >     /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/classic/core/non_terminal/impl/rule.ipp:240:36:
> >     required from ‘typename boost::spirit::classic::match_result::type
> >     boost::spirit::classic::impl::concrete_parser::do_parse_virtual(const ScannerT&) const [with ParserT =
> >     boost::spirit::classic::alternative > >,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::scanner_policies,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::kleene_star,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::alternative,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::unary_parser_category,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::non_nested, boost::spirit::classic::is_lexeme>
> >     , boost::spirit::classic::confix_parser,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::kleene_star,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::strlit,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::unary_parser_category,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::non_nested, boost::spirit::classic::is_lexeme>
> >     , boost::spirit::classic::iteration_policy>, boost::spirit::classic::match_policy,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::action_policy> >,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::nil_t, boost::spirit::classic::nil_t>,
> >     boost::property_tree::json_parser::context,
> >     std::basic_string > >::a_string_val>,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::action > >,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::scanner_policies,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::kleene_star,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::alternative,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::unary_parser_category,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::non_nested, boost::spirit::classic::is_lexeme>
> >     , boost::spirit::classic::confix_parser,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::kleene_star,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::strlit,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::unary_parser_category,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::non_nested, boost::spirit::classic::is_lexeme>
> >     , boost::spirit::classic::iteration_policy>, boost::spirit::classic::match_policy,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::action_policy> >,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::nil_t, boost::spirit::classic::nil_t>,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::strlit >,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::strlit >,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::strlit >,
> >     boost::property_tree::json_parser::context,
> >     std::basic_string > >::a_literal_val> >,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::rule > >,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::scanner_policies,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::kleene_star,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::alternative,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::unary_parser_category,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::non_nested, boost::spirit::classic::is_lexeme>
> >     , boost::spirit::classic::confix_parser,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::kleene_star,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::strlit,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::unary_parser_category,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::non_nested, boost::spirit::classic::is_lexeme>
> >     , boost::spirit::classic::iteration_policy>, boost::spirit::classic::match_policy,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::action_policy> >,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::nil_t, boost::spirit::classic::nil_t> >,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::rule > >,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::scanner_policies,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::kleene_star,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::alternative,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::unary_parser_category,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::non_nested, boost::spirit::classic::is_lexeme>
> >     , boost::spirit::classic::confix_parser,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::kleene_star,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::strlit,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::unary_parser_category,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::non_nested, boost::spirit::classic::is_lexeme>
> >     , boost::spirit::classic::iteration_policy>, boost::spirit::classic::match_policy,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::action_policy> >,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::nil_t, boost::spirit::classic::nil_t> >;
> >     ScannerT =
> >     boost::spirit::classic::scanner<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::scanner_policies,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::kleene_star,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::alternative,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::unary_parser_category,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::non_nested, boost::spirit::classic::is_lexeme>
> >     , boost::spirit::classic::confix_parser,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::kleene_star,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::strlit,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::unary_parser_category,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::non_nested, boost::spirit::classic::is_lexeme>
> >     , boost::spirit::classic::iteration_policy>, boost::spirit::classic::match_policy,
> >     boost::spirit::classic::action_policy> >; AttrT =
> >     boost::spirit::classic::nil_t; typename
> >     boost::spirit::classic::match_result::type =
> >     boost::spirit::classic::match]’
> >     main.cpp:16:1:   required from here
> >     /usr/include/boost/property_tree/detail/json_parser_read.hpp:105:17:
> >     error: no matching function for call to
> >     ‘boost::property_tree::basic_ptree,
> >     std::basic_string
> >     ::push_back(std::pair, std::basic_string >)’
> >     /usr/include/boost/property_tree/detail/json_parser_read.hpp:105:17:
> >     note: candidate is: In file included from
> >     /usr/include/boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp:516:0,
> >                      from /usr/include/boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp:13,
> >                      from main.cpp:1: /usr/include/boost/property_tree/detail/ptree_implementation.hpp:362:9:
> >     note: boost::property_tree::basic_ptree::iterator boost::property_tree::basic_ptree::push_back(const value_type&) [with Key =
> >     std::basic_string; Data = std::basic_string; KeyCompare =
> >     std::less >;
> >     boost::property_tree::basic_ptree::value_type =
> >     std::pair,
> >     boost::property_tree::basic_ptree,
> >     std::basic_string > >]
> >     /usr/include/boost/property_tree/detail/ptree_implementation.hpp:362:9:
> >     note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from
> >     ‘std::pair, std::basic_string >’ to
> >     ‘const value_type& {aka const std::pair,
> >     boost::property_tree::basic_ptree,
> >     std::basic_string > >&}’

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: Your error message is corrupted beyond comprehensibility. They key part starts close to the bottom, at "/usr/include/boost/property_tree/detail/json_parser_read.hpp:105:17: error: no matching function ", but the stuff it lists doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Sebastian Redl Yep, i already saw it, but according to the documentation, such function exists in boost 1.49 - http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp

Comment: The error refers to the internals of the library. I'm trying to find out what happened, but can't because the message is garbled.

Comment: @Sebastian Redl Unfortunately, I don't have any additional info

Comment: I just noticed that I can compile this code when I use -std=c++98 and not -std=c++11

Comment: @FrozenHeart, does the fix below do the trick for you as well?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments on OP's question, boost 1.49 does not compile with c++11 when boost::property_tree::read_json is used. It's a [known bug](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6785), and is solved by either using a more recent version of boost, or applying the the following patch:

```
--- json_parser_read.hpp        2013-09-01 03:55:57.000000000 +0400
+++ /usr/include/boost/property_tree/detail/json_parser_read.hpp        2013-09-01 03:56:21.000000000 +0400
@@ -102,7 +102,7 @@
             void operator()(It b, It e) const
             {
                 BOOST_ASSERT(c.stack.size() >= 1);
-                c.stack.back()->push_back(std::make_pair(c.name, Str(b, e)));
+                c.stack.back()->push_back(std::make_pair(c.name, Ptree(Str(b, e))));
                 c.name.clear();
                 c.string.clear();
             }
```

or

```
sed -i -e 's/std::make_pair(c.name, Str(b, e))/std::make_pair(c.name, Ptree(Str(b, e)))/' json_parser_read.hpp
```

described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552427/boost-read-json-and-c11).