# Turn QString to JSON

Tags: json, qt, qstring

I have the following:

```
QString notebookid = ui->notebookid->toPlainText();
QString tagid = ui->tagid->toPlainText();
QString userid = ui->userid->toPlainText();
QString subject = ui->subject->toPlainText();
QString comment = ui->comment->toPlainText();
```

I need to turn them into JSON, where the key is the notebookid, tagid, etc and the value is in the ui->notebookid, etc.

What's the best way to go about doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer this based on the fact that you were using Qt 4.8 and would not have the QJsonObject available from Qt5.

I use [QJSON](http://qjson.sourceforge.net/) for exactly this. It's an easy-to-use library using QVariants to parse and serialize the data.

This would be how you'd turn your data into json using QJSON:

```
QVariantMap jsonMap;
jsonMap.insert("notebookid", notebookid);
jsonMap.insert("tagid", tagid);
jsonMap.insert("userid", userid );
jsonMap.insert("subject", subject );
jsonMap.insert("comment", comment);

QJson::Serializer serializer;
bool ok;
QByteArray json = serializer.serialize(jsonMap, &ok);
assert (ok);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Qt 5, you can use `QJsonObject`. One way is to explicitly select the controls to serialize:

```
QJsonObject MyDialog::serialize() const {
  QJsonObject json;
  json.insert("notebookid", ui->notebookid->toPlainText());
  ...
  return json;
}
```

Another way is to have a generic serializer that uses the Qt's metadata. Each named control's user property is then serialized:

```
QJsonObject serializeDialog(const QWidget * dialog) {
    QJsonObject json;
    foreach (QWidget * widget, dialog->findChildren<QWidget*>()) {
        if (widget->objectName().isEmpty()) continue;
        QMetaProperty prop = widget->metaObject()->userProperty();
        if (! prop.isValid()) continue;
        QJsonValue val(QJsonValue::fromVariant(prop.read(widget)));
        if (val.isUndefined()) continue;
        json.insert(widget->objectName(), val);
    }
    return json;
}
```

You can convert `QJsonDocument` to text as follows:

```
QJsonDocument doc(serializeDialog(myDialog));
QString jsonText = QString::fromUtf8(doc.toJson());
```

Unfortunately, Qt 5's json code requires a bunch of changes to compile under Qt 4.

Comment: I assume JSON wasn't easy to deal with pre qt 5?

Comment: @Luke: Qt simply didn't provide the json classes, one could use other libraries like [boost propertytree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394472/serializing-and-deserializing-json-with-boost).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45417/discussion-between-luke-and-kuba-ober)