# How to open a file in boost

Tags: c++, boost

I am relatively new to using the boost library for c++ and I am wondering how to open a file using this. My aim is to read from a json file however I do not know how to open the file.

In c++, you can do this

```
int main () {
  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("example.txt");
  myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
  myfile.close();
  return 0;
}
```

but how can I do this using boost?

Comment: Perhaps the SO item [Serializing and deserializing json with boost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394472/serializing-and-deserializing-json-with-boost) will help.

Comment: using boost will not add much here.

Comment: Boost is just a library. It adds things that the standard library _doesn't_ have. This is **not** an example of such a thing.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `boost::filesystem::ifstream` (which works with a `boost::filesystem::path` instance) or simply use a `std::ifstream` to read the file.

The actual code depends a lot on your concrete use-case.