# Search for a Json String

Tags: c++, json

Hello I use Spirit_Json and I don't have very good knowledge of json's and was wondering how to get string/integer from this file for example.

Like a get function or something?

```
{
     "Rune_fire1": {
     "level": 1,
         "name": "Fire Rune 1",
         "damage": 1,
         "hp": 0,
         "runecost": 0,
         "defense": 0,
         "negate": 0,
         "evasion": 0,
         "healing": 0,


         "description": "The First Shard of the Fire Rune."
     },


     "Rune_fire2": {
     "level": 1,
         "name": "Fire Rune 2",
         "damage": 2,
         "hp": 0,
         "runecost": 0,
         "defense": 0,
         "negate": 0,
         "evasion": 0,
         "healing": 0,
         "description": "The Second Shard of the Fire Rune."
     },


     "Rune_fire3": {
     "level": 1,
         "name": "Fire Rune 3",
         "damage": 3,
         "hp": 0,
         "runecost": 0,
         "defense": 0,
         "negate": 0,
         "evasion": 0,
         "healing": 0,
         "description": "The Third Shard of the Fire Rune."
     },


     "Rune_fire4": {
     "level": 1,
         "name": "Fire Rune 4",
         "damage": 4,
         "hp": 0,
         "runecost": 0,
         "defense": 0,
         "negate": 0,
         "evasion": 0,
         "healing": 0,
         "description": "The Fourth Shard of the Fire Rune."
     },


     "Rune_fire5": {
     "level": 1,
         "name": "Fire Rune 5",
         "damage": 5,
         "hp": 0,
         "runecost": 0,
         "defense": 0,
         "negate": 0,
         "evasion": 0,
         "healing": 0,
         "description": "The Fifth Shard of the Fire Rune."
     },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library for json. there is one with boost-lib:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394472/serializing-and-deserializing-json-with-boost)

there is other like jsoncpp.