# Workaround for Warning C4512 From Boost's JSON Parser

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, compiler-warnings, boost-propertytree

So I'm trying to use `boost::property_tree::read_json`.

For this I need to: `#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>`

When I try though I get:

> warning C4512: `boost::property_tree::json_parser::detail::source<Encoding,Iterator,Sentinel>` : assignment operator could not be generated

I can disable this warning, but that feels particularly nasty. I would have assumed that Boost would have compiled warning free?

I'm using [visual-studio-2012](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2012) and I've seen this error on Boost 1.59.1 as well as Boost 1.65.1, and I found a [comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394472/serializing-and-deserializing-json-with-boost#comment44879978_12735086) suggesting it's been around since Boost 1.57.0. Do I have to disable this warning or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of boost headers I do the following with:

```
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable : <warning-number>)
#include <boost...>
#pragma warning(pop)
```