# Parsing to JSON in Python

Tags: python, json

I am writing a python script that transforms the object to JSON format. I've tried with the jsonpickle and also the jsondumps. But they don't seem to work.

jsonpickle says that "Pickling of instances is not enabled" and jsondumps says that "the object is not serializable".

I am exposing this in boost::python from C++, so here is the Object Model in C++:

```
struct Hosts {
        std::string hostName;
        bool isProvider;
        bool showVM;
        std::vector<std::string> vmList;
        bool operator==(Hosts const& h) const { return h.hostName == hostName; }
};
```

How do I convert the object to JSON?

Comment: What is your 'object' like? Is it a dictionary?

Comment: Please add your implementation what you have tried.

Comment: No, It is an object that is exposed using boost::python from C++.

Comment: @Abhi, Added the Code.

Comment: might be easier to convert to json using boost/C++ and then expose the result to python.

Comment: Which module should I use? Can you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394472/serializing-and-deserializing-json-with-boost/